# find the most divisible number in an array?

Tags: dynamic-programming, quicksort

Got a question in interview, find most divisible by other numbers in the array, say [2,4,8], 8 is able to be divided by 3 numbers, and that is the ans. I have a O(N^2) solution, but is there a better solution than O(N^2)?

I think, something like quick sort will make sense, but not yet get the solution, like if a % b, b%c => a%c, but % operation is not transitional like > operation.

Comment: "most divisible number in an array" - did you mean most divisible by other numbers in the array, or most divisible in general? (i.e., has the most divisors generally). Also, why is this tagged "quicksort?"

Comment: @גלעדברקן, most divisible by other numbers in the array, modified, quick sort, I want to if, this can be resolved like a sorting algo sorting by divisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with trees with O(NlogN).

The fastest algorithm i think is to make a heap (AVL tree is the best choice) tree with this rule:

For input x: find x%node[i] == 0 or node[i]%x == 0

If you found this node add x to node[i]'s children collection or replace Node[i] with x and add Node[i] to x's Children Collection.

else add this node to the root Node.